# nextJS 12 middleware breaking Plesk Site

Tags: next.js, plesk, vercel

I have nailed the issue down to the middleware as it was breaking everything. We host the site on Plesk so we understand that there maybe something that the server is doing differently.

However when I go to https://exampl.com/appstore
I should get a nice looking page but now I get
[image: Error Message]

I have tried everything to fix it, so I thought I would post here.

```
// middleware.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse, userAgent } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { os } = userAgent(request)


  if(request.nextUrl.pathname === "/appstore")
  {
    if(os.name === "iOS"){
      return NextResponse.redirect('https://apps.apple.com/au/app/drn1/id1491656217')
    }
    if(os.name === "Android"){
      return NextResponse.redirect('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drn1.drn_player')
    }
 
 }
};


export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/appstore'
  ],
}
```

I can confirm however that on Vercel servers it works fine - with no issues (https://drn-1-next-js.vercel.app/appstore).

This is what makes me think it's a plesk issue or the way NextJS dev teams have coded middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of ways this could be an issue.

1. Plesk is messing with the user agent. Your code doesn't have a fallback response (even just a 500) for the case when os.name is not one of the ones you test
2. `===` can have surprising effects. It is not a panacea. I have seen cases where APIs return wrapped values and then `===` fails. Before using `===` consider whether there is any implicit conversion that will cause an issue. As far as I can tell there is nothing reasonable that will implicitly cause `if(os.name == "Android")`  to produce a false match.

consider:

```bash
> const x = 'string';
undefined
> const y = new String('string')
undefined
> x == y
true
> y == x
true
> x === y
false
> y === x
false
>
```

Comment: Thanks, so this was able to stop it from crashing on our plesk server, however I think because we are going from a server.js file to then the nextJS it's not able to pick up the os.name function

However you have stopped the app crashing on desktops and non mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

If this is where you host: [Plesk](https://www.plesk.com/). Then Plesk doesn't currently support Next.js. They answered this about a month ago on [Plesk Support](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020714359-Does-Plesk-support-Next-JS-).

Q&A from direct form website (just in case they update the Q&A):

> Question:
> Does Plesk support Next.JS?
>
> Answer:
> Plesk does not support next.js at the moment. If you would like
> to see Next.JS support in Plesk, vote for this feature on Plesk
> UserVoice.

Comment: While Plesk does not support NextJS natively, there has been a work around for some time. Which the community agrees is best use case. We never had this issue before until we switched to the new middleware. 

We are now moving away from Plesk and over to Docker containers.